# Kendo ui custom popup binding issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mobile, kendo-dataviz

I have this on my kendo ui grid:

```
editable: {
            mode:"popup",

            template:kendo.template($("#popupGridClientes").html())

          },
```

This should be sufficient (i think!) to bind to a custom popup template which was made like this:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="popupGridClientes">

  <div class="k-edit-label"><label for="titulo">Titulo</label></div>
  <div data-container-for="titulo" class="k-edit-field"><input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" name="titulo" data-bind="value:titulo"></div>

<div class="k-edit-label"><label for="bi">Bi</label></div>
  <div data-container-for="bi" class="k-edit-field"><input id="bi" type="number" name="bi" data-bind="value:bi" 
  data-value-field="bi" data-text-field="bi" data-source="bi"></div>

I have more fields but this was only to show how i did it...

</script>
```

Now, for example, I want to set a kendoNumericTextBox to my "bi" field, so i do it like this ( has the docs say) in my .js file:

```
$("#bi").kendoNumericTextBox({
    format  : "0",
    decimals: 1,
    spinners : false
});
```

and it doesn't work, and it also doesn't work for other type of fields not only for kendonumeric!. It's not binding my custom popup template to the functions I call in my .js file, I also tried to create a **editor** to the fields but it's not working too. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widgets should be initialized with data-role attribute. I believe the following forum topic would be helpful:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-popup-editor-with-additional-fields

Comment: Thank you!. It´s working, in my index.html i only have data-bind="value:bi", and in my .js file, i had to do this: $(e.container).find("input[name='bi']").kendoNumericTextBox({
                        format  : "0",
                        decimals:0,
                        step    : 0,
                        spinners : false
                    });

Comment: but if i want to do it to other fields that need numeric box, how can i perform this?.